# "Permission denied" when writing to /dev/stdout

Tags: permissions, devices

Why cannot I write to `/dev/stdout`? I am logged in as the root user, what greater permission could I have?

```
root@ubuntu:/# tcpdump -i 2 -w /dev/stdout
tcpdump: /dev/stdout: Permission denied
```

The above command with `-w /dev/null` works. I am using stock Ubuntu Linux.

Now, `stdout` redirects to `proc` which redirects to `/dev/pts`, which is a char dev and has `w` permission -- what else is there?

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 2013-08-26 00:29 /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 2013-08-26 00:29 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 root root   64 2013-08-26 10:10 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/0
crw--w---- 1 xxx  tty  136, 0 2013-08-26 10:11 /dev/pts/0
root@ubuntu:/# tcpdump -i 2 -w /dev/pts/0
tcpdump: /dev/pts/0: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that was [apparmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page) denying that open operation.  Do you get something similar to below in your syslog?

```
kernel: [14124112.152452] type=1400 audit(1377537799.840:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=111 profile="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" name="/dev/pts/0" pid=222 comm="tcpdump" requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

By default tcpdump (without -w) passes output to stdout anyway - are you trying to get the replay data on stdout? In which case you can use `-w -` instead of `-w /dev/stdout`?

If you want to use `/dev/stdout`, and specifically `/dev/pts/*` via `apparmor`, edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump` and add an entry:

```
/dev/pts/* rw,
```

and then reload the profile:

```
apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump
```